# How to save custom taxonomy from front end post submission

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, front-end

I have been through many posts on this subject and just can't seem to wrap my head around what I need to do.

I have a form where users can submit a post to a custom post type from the from end. I want to incorporate a dropdown menu where the users can select from a custom taxonomy that I have created. I need to save the value selected when the form is submitted.

The Form:

```
 <fieldset class="jobcategorydropdown">
        <label for="jobcatdd"> Job Category </label>
        <?php wp_dropdown_categories( 'taxonomy=jobcats&hide_empty=0&name=ddjobcats' ); ?> 
</fieldset>
```

Register Taxonomy:

```
register_taxonomy('jobcats', 'job_listing', array(
'hierarchical' => true,
'labels' => $labels,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_admin_column' => true,
'query_var' => true,
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'topic' ),
```

));

Make new post:

```
function make_job_post() {

$type = 'job_listing';

$jobcatvalue = $_POST['jobcats'];


$post_information = array(
'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $_POST['postTitle'] ),
'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
'post_type' => $type,
'post_status' => 'publish',
'tax_input' => array($jobcatvalue)
);

$pid = wp_insert_post($post_information);


wp_set_object_terms($pid, $jobcatvalue,'jobcats');


}
```

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $jobcatvalue? ID? Slug?

Comment: I want it to be the value of the selection from the dropdown I guess

Answer (score 1):

If you save $jobcatsvalue make sure if it's an array of integers when saving.

```
    // Format the taxonomies
    if(is_array($_POST['jobcats'])){
        foreach($_POST['jobcats'] as $j){
            $jobcatvalue[] = intval($j);
        }
    } else {
        $jobcatvalue = array(intval($_POST['jobcats']));
    }
```